# Set Interval for each image at a different time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, setinterval

I have a simple jquery slideshow. I need to know how to change the interval time individually for each image

I only want the first image to be "9000" and the rest of them to be "3000"

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2500).next('img').fadeIn(2500).end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 9000);});
</script>

<div class="fadein" >
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
<img src="4.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Did you determine a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Just set a timeout for 9000, then set the interval for 3000:

```
$(function(){
    function fade() {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2500).next('img').fadeIn(2500).end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        fade();
        setInterval(fade, 3000);
    }, 9000);
});
```

Comment: your timeout is for 3000

Comment: that is not working for me, it pauses long on the first slide then it fades in and out real fast after that, i need it to wait 9 secs on first frame then 3 seconds on second frame, then repeat 9 again on first frame and 3 seconds on second frame,

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for.  It will at least give you something to play with.

http://jsfiddle.net/BjornJohnson/42b8X/

You set the durations you want as data attributes, which are used  by the script to set the delay for a setTimeout.

Like:

```
<div id="x">
    <img class="active" data-timeout="3000" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2644394397/748dd7e11df8dbb93f0fcf2abc141526.png" />
    <img data-timeout="1500" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3379531545/ce1eed2263515e4a173dffc815e1a6fc.jpeg" />
    <img data-timeout="5000" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3632836331/6e3f4995bd41d49b724e13e694eb1a2d.jpeg" />
    <img data-timeout="2000" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQb09ZMKsDuY5lko2JNEfnXb8_8HTfedS9Uuk_7fdcTGoH5Ps-Xxg" />
</div>
```